# Extracting polygons from layer crossed by lines layer

Tags: qgis, layers, overlapping-features, extract, intersect

I'm looking for a way to only select entities crossed by a lines layer from a polygons layer. I've unsuccessfully tried the Intersect function with lines layer overlay. I'm mentioning that I have used the same CRS for both layers.
Here what I want to do in the pictures:

Polygons layer crossed by a lines layer:

[image: area of interest]

The highlighted area I want to extract:

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run ["Select by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location) from your Processing Toolbox and choose your `polygonlayer` as *'Select features from'*, your `linelayer` as *'By comparing to the features from'* and `intersect` as *'geometric predicate'*. Your layers do not need to be in the same CRS, that is not an issue.

[image]

If you want to extract these features. You can run ["Extract by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbylocation) instead of ["Select by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location).

Comment: It worked as expected. Then I simply saved selected features

Comment: @Caligraphy or run "Extract by location". This will create a new layer containing only the features you want.

Answer (score 6):

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there two layers, a line layer `'lines'` and a polygon layer `'polygons'`.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to *extract polygons from a layer crossed by a lines layer*.

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM "polygons" AS p, "lines" AS l
WHERE st_intersects(p.geometry, l.geometry)
```

The output polygon layer (yellow) with its attribute table will look like

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

And a third solution: use QGIS expressions with geometry generator (for visualization purpose only, but it dynamically updates when you change the existing line) or `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression` to create actual geometries. In both cases apply the following expression on the line layer (and change `polygon` to the name of your polygon layer):

```
collect_geometries ( 
    overlay_disjoint( 
        'polygon',
        $geometry
    )
)
```

Remark: `overlay_disjoint` is available since QGIS 3.16.

*Screenshot: layer polygon in blue, layer line with red line and with dynamically generated yellow polygons, corresponding to those you want to keep:*
[image]

Comment: Brilliant solution and new functionnality. I will try as soon as 3.10 is no longer LT version.

Comment: 3.16 has replaced 3.10 as new LTR last month: https://qgis.org/en/site/